# Mono 2.6.7: Array Initializer Bug?

Tags: c#, arrays, mono, initialization, array-initialization

Originally Title : "Mono 2.7: Array Initializer Bug"

I'm having an issue with mono where array initialization (at least for multidimensional arrays) does not work when inlined in a method call. It looks like the mono compiler is emitting the assignments after the method call.

For instance:

```
MathLib.PrintMatrix(new double[,] { {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0} });

// Prints the following
// 0.0, 0.0
// 0.0, 0.0
```

However, the following code works correctly:

```
var myArray = new double[,] = { {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0} };

MathLib.PrintMatrix(myArray);

// Prints the following
// 1.0, 1.0
// 1.0, 1.0
```

I couldn't find any release note addressing this issue, and I'm currently running an older version (which I don't want to update unless it's going to be benificial). Does anyone know if this bug has been fixed?

Comment: Mono 2.7 is really old and, as an **odd** (7) release number, was a beta leading to 2.8 (itself pretty old).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize Mono's versioning scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have 2.7 (a beta for 2.8) around but I have something older (2.6.7 in Ubuntu)

```
poupou@mizar:~/src$ gmcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 2.6.7.0
poupou@mizar:~/src$ cat x.cs
using System;

class Program {

    static void PrintMatrix (double[,] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("{0}, {1}\n{2}, {3}", values [0,0], values [0,1], values [1,0], values [1,1]);
    }

    static void Main ()
    {
        PrintMatrix (new double[,] { {1.0, 2.0}, {3.0, 4.0} });
    }
}

poupou@mizar:~/src$ gmcs x.cs
poupou@mizar:~/src$ mono x.exe
1, 2
3, 4
```

and something a lot newer: 2.11 from **git**

```
[mono] ~/src @ mcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 2.11.0.0
[mono] ~/src @ mcs x.cs
[mono] ~/src @ mono x.exe
1, 2
3, 4
```

So I believe your issue is related to using an old, unsupported beta release of Mono.

Comment: Thanks! I'll present this to the peoples in charge :)

Comment: Actually, this is *quite* odd, as recalled the incorrect version number (I don't work directly with mono, one of my team members does). We are using 2.6.7, and it seems to have produced the correct results on your machine. Any other ideas? We're running Ubuntu as well.

Comment: No, please post a link to the entire source code so I can try it locally.

Comment: I would if I could :( (employer restrictions) . I'll have to figure this one out on my own. I'll post if I find anything particularly interesting.

Comment: Seriously ? only PrintMatrix (and only the part required to make it fail compilation for you) ? anyway you should try (if you have not already) to compile my code above - if it works then it's something else/different in your code (if it does not then make sure you're not using a different, older, compiler - e.g. --version).